# Show that $\|\phi_x - \phi_y \|=d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.Let $B(X)$ denote the real vector space of bounded real valued funtions on $X$.For $f \in B(X)$ define $\|f\|=sup\{|f(x)|:x \in X \}$.
> Fix $x_0 \in X$.For each $x\in X$,let $\phi_x:X \to \Bbb{R}$ be the function $$\phi_x(y)=d(x,y)-d(x_0,y)$$ for all $y\in X$.

> (a)Show that  $\phi_x \in B(X)$ for all $x\in X$.

> Show that $\|\phi_x - \phi_y \|=d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Solution: (a)$|\phi_x(y)|=|d(x,y)-d(x_0,y)| \le d(x,x_0)$ by reverse triangle inequality.

(b)$|\phi_x(t)-\phi_y(t)|=|d(x,t)-d(y,t)| \le d(x,y)$ for all $t \in X$.Hence $\| \phi_x - \phi_y \| \le d(x,y)$.How do I show the other direction?

Comment: What do you mean by  a linear function on a metric space?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake.It should be real valued.I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\phi_x(y)-\phi_y(y)=d(x,y)$, so $\sup_t |\phi_x(t)-\phi_y(t)| \geq d(x,y)$.

Comment: $\| \phi_x -\phi_y \| \ge |\phi_x(y)-\phi_y(y)|=d(x,y)$ ,right?

Comment: @Koushik_halder Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sup_z |\phi_x(z) - \phi_y(z)| = \sup_z |d(x,z)-d(y,z)|$$
and $|d(x,z)-d(y,z)|\leq d(x,y)$ due to the triangle inequality.

Comment: This does not answer my question.